# android studio App just says getting location and is stuck there

Tags: java, android

I am creating a speedometer app but once I run the code, all I see is a loading bar saying "Getting Location". I have noticed that if i go to application manager and give the app permission to access Location, there is no issue. So I guess my problem probably has something to do with requesting for permission. Also, after moving I noticed that my speed just keeps going up.
Heres the code:
Android Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rrithvik.speedometer2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <service android:name=".LocationService"></service>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distancetext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Total Distance:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/speedtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Instantaneous Speed:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timetext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Total Time:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="17sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="Start Calculating" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Pause"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.rrithvik.speedometer2;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    LocationService myService;
    static boolean status;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    static TextView dist, time, speed;
    Button start, pause, stop;
    static long startTime, endTime;
    ImageView image;
    static ProgressDialog locate;
    static int p = 0;

    private ServiceConnection sc = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            LocationService.LocalBinder binder = (LocationService.LocalBinder) service;
            myService = binder.getService();
            status = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            status = false;
        }
    };

    void bindService() {
        if (status == true)
            return;
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
        bindService(i, sc, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        status = true;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    void unbindService() {
        if (status == false)
            return;
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);
        unbindService(sc);
        status = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (status == true)
            unbindService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (status == false)
            super.onBackPressed();
        else
            moveTaskToBack(true);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        dist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distancetext);
        time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timetext);
        speed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedtext);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //The method below checks if Location is enabled on device or not. If not, then an alert dialog box appears with option
                //to enable gps.
                checkGps();
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

                    return;
                }


                if (status == false)
                    //Here, the Location Service gets bound and the GPS Speedometer gets Active.
                    bindService();
                locate = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                locate.setIndeterminate(true);
                locate.setCancelable(false);
                locate.setMessage("Getting Location...");
                locate.show();
                start.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause.setText("Pause");
                stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });

        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (pause.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("pause")) {
                    pause.setText("Resume");
                    p = 1;

                } else if (pause.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Resume")) {
                    checkGps();
                    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    pause.setText("Pause");
                    p = 0;

                }
            }
        });


        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (status == true)
                    unbindService();
                start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause.setText("Pause");
                pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                p = 0;
            }
        });
    }


    //This method leads you to the alert dialog box.
    void checkGps() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {


            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }
    }

    //This method configures the Alert Dialog box.
    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enable GPS to use application")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Enable GPS",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                            }
                        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

LocationService.java

```
package com.rrithvik.speedometer2;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by rrithvik on 8/16/17.
 */

public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 2;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 1;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation, lStart, lEnd;
    static double distance = 0;
    double speed;


    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        return mBinder;
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        }
    }


    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        distance = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        MainActivity.locate.dismiss();
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        if (lStart == null) {
            lStart = mCurrentLocation;
            lEnd = mCurrentLocation;
        } else
            lEnd = mCurrentLocation;

        //Calling the method below updates the  live values of distance and speed to the TextViews.
        updateUI();
        //calculating the speed with getSpeed method it returns speed in m/s so we are converting it into kmph
        speed = location.getSpeed() * 18 / 5;

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        public LocationService getService() {
            return LocationService.this;
        }


    }

    //The live feed of Distance and Speed are being set in the method below .
    private void updateUI() {
        if (MainActivity.p == 0) {
            distance = distance + (lStart.distanceTo(lEnd) / 1000.00);
            MainActivity.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diff = MainActivity.endTime - MainActivity.startTime;
            diff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
            MainActivity.time.setText("Total Time: " + diff + " minutes");
            if (speed > 0.0)
                MainActivity.speed.setText("Current speed: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(speed) + " km/hr");
            else
                MainActivity.speed.setText(".......");

            MainActivity.dist.setText(new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(distance) + " Km's.");

            lStart = lEnd;

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        lStart = null;
        lEnd = null;
        distance = 0;
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rrithvik.speedometer2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have looked everywhere, but cant seem to find an answer to this issue. Its not only me because I have seen many other people facing this problem.

Comment: I've found the issue yourself already. You are not requesting location permissions. Starting at marshmallow you have to request these in code too. Search for 'android runtime permissions' or similar to find more information.

Comment: but how do i fix the problem where my speed keeps increasing

Answer (score 0):

Woth api >= 23 one needs to request permissions at runtime usually on first boot, more efficiently, moments before they are needed.

```
requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permissions.somePermission}
```

Comment: but how would i fix the problem where my speed keeps increasing

Comment: yea this works for the requesting problem tho but the speed...?